# Exception: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, jta

I'm getting exception when trying to execute test
Please help .
Thank you in advance

**I'm using** :

Java 7 , EclipseLink 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT, Spring 3.2.4

**Test configuration file**:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="tttDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"
      />

<bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="true"
    p:databasePlatform="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="tttDataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="test-persistence.xml"
/>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="tttDataSource" 
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<!-- checks for annotated configured beans -->
<context:annotation-config/>  

<!-- Scan for Repository/Service annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.task.time.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.task.time.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.task.time.web" />
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**Exception trace** :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [testingContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addTransformer(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:348)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager$Jpa2PersistenceUnitInfoDecorator.invoke(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:617)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:111)
    ... 51 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the exception says, check [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw) and try running your test with "-javaagent", for example:

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\whatever\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\3.2.5.RELEASE\spring-instrument-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and point me to the right part of documentation

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. My solution was adding a line to context.xml on tomcat conf directory.

```
<Context>
...
    <Loader delegate="true"/>
...
</Context>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to provide that option to Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using:

```
spring-boot 1.5.3.RELEASE
spring-data 1.5.3.RELEASE

org.eclipse.persistence.jpa <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

In the configuration class add:

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)

@Bean
public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver()  throws Throwable {
    InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    return loadTimeWeaver;
}
```

Set properties file to:

```
eclipselink.weaving=false
```

And set Vm argument to local server via:

```
-javaagent:<path_to_maven_REPO>\org\springframework\spring-instrument\4.3.9.RELEASE\spring-instrument-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running maven like build, include an extra configuration to your surefire plugin, as show in this snippet (don't forget to include ${spring-version} property in your pom.xml):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <forkMode>once</forkMode>
      <argLine>
        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar"
      </argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996800/running-unit-tests-using-maven-in-spring-ltw-environment#7997064).